# VSCode notebook padding below the cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have set this: `"editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 10,` but, I'm getting a view like this, line 3 is just at the extreme bottom of the screen.
[image]

Is there any way to put some fixed space/padding below the current cursor position? In simple I don't want my cursor at the extreme bottom of the screen.

Comment: Is line 3 the last line of your file?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes the last line even goes beyond the view.

Comment: Did the answer that I posted help?

Answer (score 0):

If this happens only for the last line of your file, try adding this setting to your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false
```